# Funções JavaScript/2

Tags: javascript

Tenho que criar uma função que irá retornar uma caixa de mensagem no centro da tela com as informações dada pelo usuário, porém, tal caixa de mensagem tem quer ser feita usando a tag **div** e, é ai que está morando o problema. Abaixo está o código que estou tentando implementar.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showMessage (msg) {
            msg = prompt ('Digita Mensagem' );          
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#div1").fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
            });         
        }       
    </script>

<style>
    #div1 {
        background-color: #90EE90;
        border-style: hidden;
        border-color: #98FB98;
        position: absolute;
        left: 700px;
        top: 400px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "div1">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo, basta usar o retorno do seu `prompt()` e atribuir ao conteúdo da sua div.

```js
function showMessage() {
  var msg = prompt('Digita Mensagem');
  $("#div1").text(msg).fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
}

showMessage();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#div1 {  
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  text-align: center;  
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #90EE90;
  border-color: #98FB98;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Executando pelo site, da numa boa, mas, ao montar o código na IDE a mensagem não está sendo exibida. Pode ser a ordem que está errada?

Comment: Que IDE? Não exibe o texto ou não abre o prompt?